# Nested map bracket initialization fails to compile

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

Tiny, very simple code example that showcases the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

static std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> defaults = {
    { std::string("Definitely a string"), { std::string("This too"), 0 }},
};
```

The error? `main.cpp:4:58: No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int> >'`

Comment: My compiler (g++) gives a similar (but much more verbose) error that boils down to "Can't convert from initializer list to map"... I don't know why the error happens though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need an extra pair of braces:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

static std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> defaults = {
    { std::string("Definitely a string"), {{ std::string("This too"), 0 }}},
//                                        ^                              ^
};
```

It's basically the same way as initializing the outer map - the inner map needs to be initialized with an initializer list - one pair of braces - that contains initializer lists for the key-value pairs of the map - another pair of braces per element.

As Matt McNabb noted, you don't have to explicitly construct the `std::string`s.

Comment: Interesting, and totally non-obvious. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that `std::string` has implicit constructor, so you can also put `{ "string 1", {{ "string 2", 0 }} }`

Comment: @LulzCop `std::map` entry is initialized by a key,value pair . It doesn't automatically group everything after the key into a set of value initializers, you have to mark that off.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I know, it was just to prevent the possibility of someone thinking that the problem was that the compiler was preferring c-strings over std::string, as one person I showed it to thought.